# How do I get economical/conflict data on Galaxy Map?

Tags: no-mans-sky

The new update 1.3 has added economical data however I am unable to figure out how to get this data on the galactic map. Is there some sort of technology that needs to be installed?

Comment: I'm not adding this as an answer because it doesn't say where to find it, but the [No Man's Sky Website](http://www.nomanssky.com/atlas-rises-update/) says *Install galactic technology to be able to filter the map by lifeform, wealth and economy.*

Comment: I did see that but I have no idea where to get this technology. I suspect it may have something to do with getting rankings in the guilds but maybe I am wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this guide](http://gameplay.tips/guides/919-no-mans-sky.html), the new Economical and Conflict blueprints can be purchased at various blueprint vendors - you can find these within the space station. If your current star system does not have the blue print, simple hop to another one until you locate it

> Firstly, you're going to want to find a blueprint vendor actually selling the blueprint to build one. It should cost around 400 nanite clusters to buy one however I'm not sure if this canges depending on the solar system you're in.

After you have the blueprint, it doesn't take a whole lot to build it

> Once you have the blueprint you going to want around 200 Thamium and Heridium to build the tech. (I advise building it in a tech slot onboard your ship to avoid wasting cargo space.)

Once your technology has been built, you can install it into your ship to and load up the galactic map

Comment: Thanks, I actually came across the Conflict scanner while playing last night, and promptly bought it.